# Where do I find help on formatting my post?

Tags: support, formatting

When asking, editing or answering I often do not know how to format my text to look better.

Where do I find an overview on formatting tools availabe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we ask a question or edit a question we will have a panel with most frequently needed formatting tools. Hover over any tool to get a small help box displayed:

[image]

Click on one of the Entries from *"Links  Images  Styling  ... etc."* to get more help on how to use these formats. Click on *"advanced help"* for more information.

In addition there is a box on the right side of the screen:

#### When asking:

[image] and [image]

The *"How to Ask"* box will be replaced by the *"How To Format"* box as soon as we start typing our question.

#### When editing:

[image]

There you find a link to the corresponding help page on "[formatting help](https://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help)". This will lead to the following page:

- [Markdown help](https://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

For finer edits using HTML and Markdown tags see the following post on meta.stackoverflow:

- [What HTML tags are allowed on StackExchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)